# How to perform an action only when a new non-empty message from the KAFKA topic arrived , in Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a static Dataframe(csv file) and an KAFKA topic(say Topic1) as input to join both of them and perform required transformations and writing back to another topic.

The new challenge is ,There will be an additional topic(Topic2) that notify the changes in CSV file.
whenever there is a message from Topic2 , I have to re-read the static Dataframe join them with Kafka message(of Topic1).

How to conditionalize the reading Dataframe part, only when there is a message arrived from Topic2?
Please ask me if I need to be more clear.

I can't think of any DStream equivalent of "foreachRDD {... rdd.count>0 ..}" in Structured Streaming, as queryStream evaluated lazily.
So I can't do any action to determine whether the Topic2 delivered a message or not.

Below is my sample code:

```
var staticDF = getLookupDataframe(spark,filePath)

val topic1DataStream =spark
        .readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .options(KAFKA_Topic1_Properties)
        .load()
        .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schemaForJson).as("parseddata"))
        .select("parseddata.*")

val topic2DataStream =spark
        .readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .options(KAFKA_Topic2_Properties)
        .load()
        .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schemaForJson).as("parseddata"))
        .select("parseddata.*")


if(/*condition to determine the Topic2 message arrival*/)
{
staticDF = getLookupDataframe(spark,filePath)
}

doSomeOperations(staticDF,topic1DataStream)




def getLookupDataframe(spark: SparkSession, path: String) :DataFrame = {
    spark
      .read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("delimiter", " ")
      .load(path)
      .toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch`?

Comment: Yes. I tried foreachBatch and with that I am able to find the count of topic2. But the problem is, doSomeOperation function having complex transformation and end result will be a stream write to kafka topic(its the final result) . But two streams are not working in parallel. Once you get into doSomeOperation there is only stream (which is topic1 stream). Not coming to IF block even if there is message in topic2.

Comment: I mean 'Control is not coming back to IF block even if there is message in topic2.'

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Can you please see the code 
https://github.com/rajeshs903/MonitoredStructuredStreaming/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/ss/service/EmployeeDeptEnrichmentService.scala